# slider with opacity and z-index not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

i am quite new to JQuery.
I am working on a slider which shows the image when the thumb is clicked. 
Now i have given some data-roles to the thumbs and the full image so that if thumb no.3 is clicked, the full image of data-id 3 is set to opacity 1 and z-index larger.
Somehow, the slider works first time when the thumbs are clicked, but when i click on second time the image is not shown which has same i as thumb.
here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="sliderContainer">
    <!--Filters -->
    <ul id="filterList">
        <li>All</li>
        <li>Objects</li>
        <li>Fashion</li>
        <li>Nature</li>
    </ul>

    <span id="titleText">asdsd</span>
    <!--Thumbs List-->
    <ul id="thumbsList">
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="1" data-title="Girl Eating Something"><img src="images/fashion/fashion1Thumb.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="2" data-title="Beautiful Face"><img src="images/fashion/fashion2Thumb.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="3" data-title="Cinderella"><img src="images/fashion/fashion3Thumb.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="4" data-title="Apple Mobile"><img src="images/objects/object1Thumb.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="5" data-title="Coke Can"><img src="images/objects/object2Thumb.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="thumbs" data-thumbid="6" data-title="Mountains"><img src="images/nature/nature1thumb.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>


    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="1" src="images/fashion/fashion1Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="2" src="images/fashion/fashion2Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="3" src="images/fashion/fashion3Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="4" src="images/objects/object1Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="5" src="images/objects/object2Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="6" src="images/nature/nature1Full.jpg" />
    <img class="productsSliderImage" data-fullimageid="7" src="images/nature/nature1Full.jpg" />

</div>
```

and here is my JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".productsSliderImage").css('opacity', '0');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbs').click(function () {
        var currentThumbId = $(this).attr("data-thumbid"); //grab thumbId of clicked thumb.
        //Changing css of the fullscreenImage which is equal to clcked thumb.
        //Animation is done using Opacity in css.
        $('.productsSliderImage[data-fullImageId="' + currentThumbId + '"]').css('z-index', '33');
        $('.productsSliderImage[data-fullImageId="' + currentThumbId + '"]').css('opacity', '1');
        var notClicked = $('.productsSliderImage[data-fullImageId="' + currentThumbId + '"]').not(this);
        notClicked.css('opacity', '1');
        notClicked.css('z-index', '1');
    });
});
```

And my Css

```
.productsSliderImage {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry i am quite new, i do not know how to create a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Basically you can do something like this
.animation

{
blah blah blah
}
then i jquery, you can use something like this onclick()

```
$('#abc').addClass('animation');
```

and the same way you can remove class. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

**CSS**

```
.animate{
   zIndex:33;
   opacity:1
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.thumbs').click(function () {
    var thumbId = $(this).data("thumbid"); //use data function    
    // remove class for all products
    $('.productsSliderImage').removeClass('animate');
    // set current product image class to overlap
    $('.productsSliderImage[data-fullImageId="'+thumbId+'"]').addClass('animate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a class with the properties you wanna add such as z index and opacity rather than writing lengthy code.
you can use addClass() and removeClass() methods to do that. 
Read here [addClass() Method Info.](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Thanks.

Comment: Basically whatever you do with css can be packed in a file and used like attaching and detaching stuff. thanks.